# How can I align an image to the center in a Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

Stupid question: I have three images in a row, but they are aligned to the left in their column. How can I align them to the center of the column?

This is my code:

```
 <div class="container partners">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<img src="swz.png" alt="streetwize" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<img src="ogon.png" alt="ogon" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">  
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<img src="congaz.png" alt="ogon" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">    
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.partners {
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the text-center class to your column divs

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not write 2 class tag on same element

```
<img src="swz.png" alt="streetwize" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">
```

instead of this you can write `class="img-circle img-responsive"`

for center aligning u can use `"text-center"` class to parent div..
or you can also apply `style="float:none; margin:0 auto;"` to img.

thanks, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make image `block` element and margin of auto. but as the `margin:auto` won't work except you assign some width of the elemet.

```
.partners img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```css
.partners {
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.partners img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container partners">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<img src="swz.png" alt="streetwize" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<img src="ogon.png" alt="ogon" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">  
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
<img src="congaz.png" alt="ogon" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">    
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-center">
<img src="swz.png" alt="streetwize" class="img-circle" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:180px">
</div>
```

it would work defiantly.